# Preserve contents of clipboard when a programs from text from copied exits

Tags: gnome, gnome3, clipboard

In GNOME 3 when I copy some text to clipboard from an application and then exit from that application, the clipboard doesn't hold the copied text (the clipboard is empty). My question is as follows:

**How do I make GNOME 3 to not remove the contents of the clipboard when the application I copied text from exits?**

Comment: Read this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence and install clipboard indicator Gnome extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem indicated in the question is so called "Clipboard Persistence bug", which is described, for example, [in Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence).

The best workaround for Gnome 3 is to install Clipboard Indicator Gnome extension which is available at the following link: [Clipboard Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/).

If you're on Ubuntu, pay your attention that since Ubuntu 18.04 version its users can install Gnome Extensions directly from Ubuntu Software Center by typing in search field of the app phrase: "Gnome extensions ", for example:

[image: Ubuntu Software Center - Gnome Extensions]